# Is GraphQL valid GraphQL+?

Tags: graphql, dgraph

The following is true:

```
Javascript == Typescript
Typescript != Javascript
```

Can the same be said for Dgraph's GraphQL+?

```
GraphQL == GraphQL+
GraphQL+ != GraphQL
```

The reason for asking, I understand that GraphQL is not sufficient for Dgraph's goals. But does it process GraphQL if needed?

Comment: "The following is true" - bad choice of operators. As it is now, the assertions don't make any sense. Equality is a symmetric operation. If a == b, then b == a.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first paragraph on their landing page reads:

> We’ve modified the language to better support graph operations, adding and **removing** features

And also this

> GraphQL+- is a work in progress. We’re adding more features and we might further simplify existing ones.

This means that these languages are incompatible. Similar, yes, but each have unique features.

Answer (score 7):

To add to Sergio's answer, GraphQL+- is not fully compatible with GraphQL. We liked GraphQL and used that as a basis for a new graph query language.

However, I think we would likely look at how big of a gap is between GraphQL+- and GraphQL, and if can be bridged, we would (probably close to or after v1.0).

Comment: Thanks for the input Manish